# Multiple Div Fade In/Out On

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three divs, each containing multiple images.

There are also three buttons on the page.

I would like to create an effect where clicking on each button fades in the corresponding div and fades out the other two divs.

I have tried to follow code posted previously for similar effects, but have been unsuccessful and am hoping for some help from those who have more skill than I do! Thanks, Ross

The HTML is as follows;

```
 <div id="GROUP-Join">
    <img class="CentreBox" src="images/CentreBox.png" 
        width="487" height="173">
    <img id="TitleOne" src="images/TitleOne.png" 
        width="339" height="19">
    <img id="TitleTwo" src="images/TitleTwo.png" 
        width="143" height="14">
    <body onLoad="focus();signup.email.focus()"></body>
    <form method="post" name="signup" action="signup.php">
        <input id="EmailAddress" type="text" name="email" 
            placeholder="e-mail" style="color: #000000; 
            font-family: 'Arial'; font-size: 20px; background-color:transparent;     
            border:hidden;" size="24" maxlength="49">
        <input id="Go" type="image" name="submit" src="images/Go.png" 
            alt="submit" value="GO">   
    </form>
 </div>
 <div id="GROUP-About">
    <img class="CentreBox" src="images/CentreBOX.png" 
        width="487" height="173">
    <img id="AboutHead" src="images/AboutHead.png" 
        width="132" height="19">
    <img id="JumpAround" src="images/JumpAround.png" 
        width="379" height="33">
    <img id="Win" src="images/Win.png" 
        width="254" height="15">    
 </div>
 <div id="GROUP-Contact">
    <img class="CentreBox" src="images/CentreBOX.png" 
        width="487" height="173">
    <img id="ContactHeading" src="images/ContactHead.png" 
        width="124" height="19">
    <img id="Email" src="images/e-mail.png" 
        width="24" height="17">
    <img id="Twitter" src="images/tw.png" 
        width="24" height="20">
    <img id="fb" src="images/fb.png" 
        width="10" height="21">    
 </div>
 <button id="button1">Join</button>
 <button id="button2">About</button>
 <button id="button3">Contact</button>
```

Comment: I see some markup, but no actual code that you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're meaning, but this will fade in each corresponding div and fade out the other two.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn1').click(function () {
            $('#div1').fadeIn();
            $('#div2').fadeOut();
            $('#div3').fadeOut();
        });
        $('#btn2').click(function () {
            $('#div1').fadeOut();
            $('#div2').fadeIn();
            $('#div3').fadeOut();
        });
        $('#btn3').click(function () {
            $('#div1').fadeOut();
            $('#div2').fadeOut();
            $('#div3').fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the markup:

```
<div>
    <div id="div1">
        hello
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        hello 2
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        hello 3
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btn1" />
        <input type="button" id="btn2" />
        <input type="button" id="btn3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions also have callbacks, so you could also do:

```
$('#div2').fadeOut(100, 
    function() { $('#div3').fadeOut(100, 
            function() { $('#div1').fadeIn(100); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I have noticed that in IE, when toggling through each button, when it returns to the Join page it is no longer possible to select the emailaddress input box. Is there any way that this can be fixed?

Comment: What version of IE? I tried it in 7, 8 and 9 and it works in all 3. Also - why do you have a body tag in the middle of your GROUP-Join div? There should only be 1 body tag in your markup, surrounding your content.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/sHaUX/)

This script should get the work done for you

```
$(function(){

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var btnText = $(this).text();

        $('div').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#GROUP-'+btnText).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks sushanth, that's working brilliantly, the only problem is that it makes the rest of the content on the page disappear. Is there a way to stop this happening?

Comment: What is the content you are talking about.??

Answer (score 0):

When you run an effect in jQuery such as fadeIn, you can provide a callback so that you can perform actions once that effect has completed. For instance, in your case:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
  $('#GROUP-Contact').fadeOut(500);
  $('#GROUP-About').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#GROUP-Join').fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

This is my best guess of what you are looking for without seeing any JS code.